# std::map::const_iterator leaks non-const reference to value?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I've observed that a std::map::const_iterator leaks a non-const reference to the value_type:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::map<int,int> foo = {{1,1},{4,2}};
  const auto &m = foo;
  const auto &it = foo.find(1);
  printf("%d %d\n", it->first, it->second);
  int &i = it->second;
  i = 3;
  auto &one = foo.at(1);
  printf("%d %d\n", 1, one);
  return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out 
1 1
1 3
```

Is this expected? Why? Is the only way to codify const-protection of the std::map is to wrap it in another class?

Comment: What make you think you are using a const_iterator?

Comment: `foo.find(1)` returns an *iterator*. Maybe you meant to write `m.find(1)` (which does return a *const_iterator* and would therefore yield a compilation error)

Comment: Doh! Thanks @UnholySheep. That's the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
const auto &it = foo.find(1);
```

creates `const reference` to `std::map<int,int>::iterator` named `it`, so you cannot modify `it` itself or iterator it refers to, but can modify data it points to (as iterator). It is similar to constant pointer vs pointer to const data. Use `m` to get `std::map<int,int>::const_iterator` with type auto deduction (it does not have to be const reference) or give it explicit type:

```
std::map<int,int>::const_iterator it = foo.find(1);
```

then you cannot modify data through that iterator.

Comment: I'm markign this as the accepted answer but I'll also note that my original code was flawed as @UnholySheep noted above. I should have done / meant to do "m.find(1)".

Comment: @PatrickDonnelly did you read my answer? I also mentioned using `m` as one of solutions to your problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I admit I skimmed over that part of your answer! Thanks again!